# Java redrawing duplicate image

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, duplicates

So ive been doing a bit of java recently and i have run into a bit of a problem. I have been playing around with 2d drawing and added an image to the project.

The problem is that when the window gets resized, it redraws and duplicates the image. I have made a little workaround, but its not ideal... So why does the image duplicate?

Before:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceDfV.png

(window is resized)

After:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zsz4.png

Code

main.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class main
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Title");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Canvas testing = new Canvas();

        f.add(testing);
        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

canvas.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Canvas extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {



        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 30);

        g.setColor(new Color(190,81,215));
        g.fillRect(25, 68, 10, 10);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("Matt is da best", 100, 10);


            try
            {
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/face.png"));
                JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
                System.out.println("Added pic");
                add(picLabel);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't load the image in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method!  It could be declared as a class attribute and loaded in the constructor.
2. Don't add components in the `paintComponent` method either!  It will trigger a repaint.

This should work more reliably..

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class main
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Title");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Canvas testing = new Canvas();

        f.add(testing);
        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Canvas extends JPanel
{

    BufferedImage image;

    Canvas() {
        image = new BufferedImage(200,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        System.out.println("Added pic");
        add(picLabel);
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 30);

        g.setColor(new Color(190,81,215));
        g.fillRect(25, 68, 10, 10);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("Matt is da best", 100, 10);
    }
}
```

### Other tips

- Have the `Canvas` return a preferred size and `pack()` the frame rather than set a size to it.
- Start and update a Swing GUI on the EDT.
- Don't give your custom class the same name as a J2SE class.  That can get confusing.  Maybe call it `JCanvas`.

Comment: Thanks! Works great. I actually did not expect a reply for a few days, let alone within 15 minutes. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your `paintComponent` method...

Each time `paintComponent` is called, you are creating a new `JLabel` and adding it back to the panel...

```
try
{
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/face.png"));
    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    System.out.println("Added pic");
    add(picLabel);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This in turn will produce another repaint request and the sync will begin all over again.

NEVER modify the state of any component from within any `paint` method.  This will simple...blow up in your face...

You should load your image and add the label within the constructor or some other method (that `paintXxx` doesn't call)

The important thing to remember about painting in Swing is, you don't control it.  The repaint engine may update your component at any time, with or without your interaction, based on it's own needs.  You can encourage a paint by calling `repaint`, but there is no guarantee of when or what will be repainted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well. It was nice and specific and told me exactly what i was doing wrong. Thanks!